# Assign value to a pointer array give me error while using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, pointers

When I do this pointer arithmetic , it always give me an error

```
int main()
{
    const int rowSize=40;
    int* unique=nullptr;

    int arr[rowSize]={1,1,11,31,21,22,2,2,3,32,31,3,4,34,45,5,55,5,55,5,6,46,64,6,7,27,74,7,7,7,7,11,11,11,11,11,1,2,13,4};
    int amount=0;

    for (int count=0; count<rowSize; count++)
    {
        if (arr[count]!=arr[count+1])
        {
            amount++;
        }
    }
    unique= new int[amount];
    for (int count=0; count<rowSize-1; count++)
    {
        if (arr[count]!=arr[count+1])
        {
            *unique=arr[count];
            unique++;
        }
    }

    for (int count=0; count<20; count++)
    {
        cout<<unique[count]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    delete [] unique;
    unique=nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Everytime I do this pointer arithmetic, *unique=arr[count] and unique++, it always give me a funky output at the end.

Comment: Does this code compile? What is the value of `RowSize`?

Comment: int the line `if( arr[count] != arr[count+1])` when `count` is on the last element (`rowSize -1`) you access `arr[count+1]` where `count+1 == rowSize` this is out of range of your array. The last element is then just some garbage value ;)

just make your loop `for (int count=0; count < rowSize - 1; count++)` and everthing will work.

Comment: @cigien MB, rowSize=40 I forgot to put it during copying this code. it is just a piece of function, it compile thou but it just give a funny output.

Comment: You might *think* that the information you leave out is not relevant. But we cant know that, so you should always provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @cigien, well there I edit it so it should be compilable.

Comment: @Dimfred, it still give me a funny output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the value of a pointer returned by the `new[]` operator is extremely dangerous, and never really the right way to go about coding. This is because, at some point, you will need to release that memory with a `delete[]` 'call' to the address that `new[]` gave you.

In your case, the module that calls your `uniqueArr` function gets a returned value that will **no longer** (in most cases) be the correct address for the `delete[]` call, and that will fail.

You would be *far better off* using the `[]` operator on your pointer, using an index value that you increment when appropriate (where you currently increment the pointer). Something like this:

```cpp
//...
    int* unique = new int[amount];
    size_t uIndex = 0;

    for (int count=0; count<rowSize-1; count++)
    {
        if (arr[count]!=arr[count+1])
        {
            unique[uIndex] = arr[count]; // The [] works fine with a 'new[]' pointer!
            uIndex++; // You could even include this POST-increment inside the [], above!
        }
    }
//... You can now 're-use' "unique" as it will still be the original address.
//...
```

In this way, the value returned by the function will be unchanged from that returned by the `new[]` operator, and will be valid for any subsequent `delete[]` operation.

Feel free to ask for further clarification an/or explanation.

*EDIT: An alternative (though, IMHO not good) approach would be to have a second `int*` pointer in which you save the value of `unique`, then restore `unique` to that value before 're-using' it (in a second loop, or before calling `delete[]`).*

Comment: Well, thanks for the help it give me the right output.